# Solving a Pell-like equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

How to solve the equation

$x^2-20y^2=400$?

Is there a general method that reduces the equation $x^2-ay^2=b$ to $x'^2-a'y'^2=1$?

Comment: Divide both sides by 400?  You'll have $\left(\frac{x}{20}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{20}y}{20}\right)^2=1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219  you can use other formulas.

Comment: See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

First solve the equation $x^2 - 20y^2 = 1$. The trivial solution is $(x,y) = (9,2)$. Now try to find a solution to the equation $x^2 - 20y^2 = 400$. The trivial solution is $(x,y) = (20,0)$. Hence we have that the solutions are given by:

$$x_n + y_n\sqrt{20} = (20 + 0\sqrt{20})(9 + 2\sqrt{20})^n$$

In fact as $400$ is a full square you can divide by it and try to solve $x'^2 - 20y'^2 = 1$, where $x' = \frac{x}{20}$ and $y'= \frac{y}{20}$

Comment: @user236182 Yeah, you're right! I mixed the up

Comment: $(x,y)=(30,5)$ is a solution of $x^2 - 20y^2 = 400$, but $20\nmid 30$ and $20\nmid 5$.

Comment: All your methods don't give the set of all solutions, because they give solutions $(x,y)$ where $20\mid x$ and $20\mid y$, but there exists a solution, e.g., $(x,y)=(30,5)$, where this is not true. The first method gives $x_n+y_n\sqrt{20}=20(9+2\sqrt{20})^n$ solutions where $20\mid x_n$, $20\mid y_n$. The second method too.

Comment: @user236182 Actually each solution gives rise to a particular family of solutions. If you use $(x,y) = (30,5)$ and $x_n + y_n\sqrt{20} = (30 + 5\sqrt{20})(9 + 2\sqrt{20})^n$ you will get a lot other solutions.

Comment: The solution $(x,y)=(9,2)$ of $x^2-20y^2=1$ may be called "nontrivial" and the "trivial" solution $(x,y)=(\pm 1,0)$. E.g., for a fixed positive integer $d$ that is not a square, the equation $x^2-dy^2=1$ has a "nontrivial" solution. In the paper linked by one of the comments, currently KCd, this is Theorem $2.3$ (Lagrange) in the $2$nd page. In the beginning of the paper the "trivial" meaning is explained.

Answer (score 1):

As sometimes happens, the four orbits here under the automorphism group of $x^2 - 20 y^2$ can be combined into a single orbit; we get solutions $x_n^2 - 20 y_n^2 = 400$ with non-negative integers $(x_n,y_n)$ and
$$ x_{n+2} = 3 x_{n+1} - x_n, $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 3 y_{n+1} - y_n. $$
The first few pairs are
$$ (20,0); \; \;  (30,5); \; \;  (70,15); \; \;  (180,40); \; \;  (470,105); \; \ldots   $$

My program calls them w,v.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    9   40
    2   9
  Automorphism backwards:  
    9   -40
    -2   9

  9^2 - 20 2^2 = 1

 w^2 - 20 v^2 = 400

Mon Oct  9 11:34:09 PDT 2017

w:  20  v:  0  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  30  v:  5  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  70  v:  15  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  30 ,  -5
w:  180  v:  40  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  20 ,  0
w:  470  v:  105
w:  1230  v:  275
w:  3220  v:  720
w:  8430  v:  1885
w:  22070  v:  4935
w:  57780  v:  12920
w:  151270  v:  33825
w:  396030  v:  88555
w:  1036820  v:  231840
w:  2714430  v:  606965
w:  7106470  v:  1589055
w:  18604980  v:  4160200
w:  48708470  v:  10891545
w:  127520430  v:  28514435

Mon Oct  9 11:35:09 PDT 2017

 w^2 - 20 v^2 = 400

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```